# Android Fragment popupmenu with LogCat

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FestivalFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView diwali, contacts,setting;

    PopupMenu popupmenu;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_festival, container,false);

     diwali = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagediwali);
     diwali.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intdiwali = new Intent(getActivity(),Category.class);
            startActivity(intdiwali);

        }
    });



    //return rootView;

     contacts = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagecontacts);
     contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intcontact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivity(intcontact);
        }
    });

    // return rootView;


     setting = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesettings);
     setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            showPopupMenu(view);


        }
    });


     return rootView;
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        PopupMenu popupmenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
        popupmenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.festival, popupmenu.getMenu());
        popupmenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuitem) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(menuitem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item_logout:

                    Intent intlogout = new Intent(getActivity(),Logout.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intlogout);
                    break;
            case R.id.item_changepass:
                    Intent intchange = new Intent(getActivity(),Changepassword.class);
                   getActivity().startActivity(intchange);
                    break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        popupmenu.show();
    }
}
```

I am getting Error in AndroidRuntime `showPopupMenu()` method, `popupmenu.show()` and I have tried it many times but cannot run the program so please help me solve this.

Comment: add your logcat error

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your `private void showPopupMenu(View view) {...` method should be in the `onCreateView` method ***except*** `popupmenu.show();`.